# Listbox height gets replaced by other value?

Tags: c#, listbox, size

I am breaking my head over this all morning.

I created a user control with a textbox and a listbox. The listbox should show all items which contains the text entered in the textbox.

It is supposed to be a combobox with Like Search Capabilities.

All the searching works only the resizing of the listbox fails at a certain point and i cant figure out what the problem is.

The code below is executed perfectly. But after the invalidation of `lbresult` the height of `lbresults` sets to 4 when the viewableRows = 1

Under the code is the output generated by the console statements

```
if (this.lbResults.Visible)
{
            int viewableRows = this.lbResults.Items.Count;
            Console.WriteLine(viewableRows.ToString());
            if (viewableRows > this.maxItemsDisplayed)
            {
                viewableRows = this.maxItemsDisplayed;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(viewableRows.ToString());

            int lbresults_height = ((viewableRows) * 15) ;

            Console.WriteLine(lbresults_height);

            this.ResizeControl(this.Width, this.txtSearch.Height + lbresults_height);
            this.lbResults.Size = new Size(this.lbResults.Width, lbresults_height);
            this.lbResults.Invalidate();
            Console.WriteLine("Listbox Height: " + lbResults.Height.ToString());
        }
        else if(!this.lbResults.Visible)
        {
            this.ResizeControl(this.Width, this.txtSearch.Height);
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
15
```

Listbox Height: 4

I can't find any reason why it should be set to 4...

Please help me.

Comment: What's the "ResizeControl" statement? Is it something you've defined yourself? Is it resetting something? Is this WinForms or WPF? N.

Comment: @Nick I defined that myself

Comment: @nick Don't you see my answer? You don't need to ask these questions. This behaviour is the normal output from the IntegralHeight property.

Comment: @varocarbas No, I didn't see your answer - we were typing at the same time. N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you describe happens, most likely, because `IntegralHeight` is set to true ([MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.integralheight.aspx)). If you want the `ListBox` to the get as height exactly the same value that you are inputing, just disable this option:

```
this.lbResults.IntegralHeight = false;
```

On the other hand, bear in mind that this is not a bad-to-have feature. When this option is enabled, C# takes the height value you input as a suggestion and adapt it too meet the target: the final height of the ListBox has to be divisible by the height of each item (the real height, that is, ItemHeight + lag between items).

Comment: but is the itemheight = 13
shoud it not display the first item.
because 15 / 13  = 1.xxx = 1

Comment: @user214623 No. It is the REAL height, the one you see (it is a bit bigger than itemheight). Do some tests by your own, to confirm what I am saying: if you do what I suggested, you would stop seeing this problem. If you let IntegralHeight enabled, and do some calcs with simple examples, you would see that the height considered is around itemheight + 1.2 (default font size).

Comment: I have to say it :D
You are absolutly amazing :D

Comment: @user214623 Happy to have been of help.